# ServiceStack Jwt authentication check if authenticated

Tags: session, authentication, servicestack, jwt

I need to allow anonym access endpoint but still check if user is authenticated then give some extra data.

using [Authenticate] attribute I can use

```
var session = SessionAs<AuthUserSession>();
```

and then session.IsAuthenticated

it works just fine but without [Authenticated] attribute session is empty(new session is generated with new id and all props is not populated with user data)

How to check if user is authenticated without [Authenticate] attibute with request which uses jwt token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [JwtAuthProvider](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider) is an `IAuthWithRequest` provider which only validates the JWT Token and returns the appropriate HTTP Error Response if the token is invalid **when it needs to Authenticate the the Request**, e.g. when Services annotated with the `[Authenticate]` attribute. If Services don't require Authentication, the `IAuthWithRequest` Auth Providers and JWT Bearer Tokens aren't validated and the Users Session isn't automatically populated.

But in the latest [v4.5.9 that's now on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget) new APIs have been added to JWT AuthProvider to be able to create custom JWT Tokens and convert them into User Sessions, specifically you can create a UserSession from a JWT Token with:

```
var session = JwtAuthProvider.CreateSessionFromJwt(base.Request);
```

Which is [just a helper](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Auth/JwtAuthProviderReader.cs#L483) for resolving the registered `JwtAuthProviderReader` and calling its `ConvertJwtToSession()` API:

```
var jwtProvider = (JwtAuthProviderReader)
    AuthenticateService.GetAuthProvider(JwtAuthProviderReader.Name);
var session = jwtProvider.ConvertJwtToSession(base.Request, base.Request.GetJwtToken());
```

Comment: I am using asp.net core and using code you provided it thows exception JwtAuthProvider line 453. any ideas?

Comment: base.Request.GetJwtToken(); is null. I am using typescript client and all fine as I mentioned with attribute.

Comment: @Roman can you update your question with the TypeScript client request that's sending the token

Comment: Where in the code would you call `CreateSessionFromJwt`? Can it be done in a single place?